# How to read the text placed in the element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

let's suppose i have a paragraph element

```
<p id="dynamic">  </p>
```

In the element the data is dynamically placed. How do I read the text which is placed ?

Comment: Where is your code so far?

Comment: You forgot the left inner bracket and JavaScript as well

Comment: https://github.com/andrastoth/WebCodeCam     i was actually trying to read the scanned qrcode value which is placed dynamically in index.html  in <p id="scanned-QR" ></p>   .The data in the paragraph tag is changed by main.js

Comment: Question displays a serious lack of research effort or attempts to solve issue yourself. Both are expected here as outlined in [ask] and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @charlietfl  sorry i am a newbie.  link :github.com/andrastoth/WebCodeCam i was actually trying to read the scanned qrcode value which is placed dynamically in index.html in <p id="scanned-QR" ></p> .The data in the paragraph tag is placed by manipulating  in main.js

Comment: Understood but there are lots of tutorials on web that you can learn the basics from

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="dynamic" hidden>Test</p>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var p = document.getElementById('dynamic');
        console.log(p.firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
</script>
```

`firstChild` get the first child node of a node element, here it's a text node.
`nodeValue` get the text of a text node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for the solution. JQuery provides `.text()` for getting the value inside the tag. 
see this,
https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/9ajssfma/

```
var val = $('p').text();
```

this is the documentation, http://api.jquery.com/text/